# Dask DataFrame filter and repartition gives some empty partitions

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to filter a Dask `DataFrame` and then use `map_partitions` to apply a function to each partition. The function expects a pandas `DataFrame` with at least 1 row.

Here is the code to generate some dummy data as a `pandas` `DataFrame` (and then convert to Dask `DataFrame`) for a MCVE

```
def create_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6 * n), columns=["A"])
    random_integers = np.random.default_rng().choice(14, size=n, replace=False)
    df.insert(0, 'store_id', [d for s in random_integers for d in [s] * 6])
    return df

df = create_data(n=10)
print(df.head(15))
>>>
    store_id         A
0         10  0.850730
1         10  0.581119
2         10  0.825802
3         10  0.657797
4         10  0.291961
5         10  0.864984
6          9  0.161334
7          9  0.397162
8          9  0.089300
9          9  0.435914
10         9  0.750741
11         9  0.920625
12         3  0.635727
13         3  0.425270
14         3  0.904043
```

Structure of the data: for each `store_id`, there are exactly 6 rows.

Now I create a list of some number of `store_id`s that I want to use to filter the above data

```
filtered_store_ids = df["store_id"].value_counts().index[:6].tolist()
print(filtered_store_ids)
>>> [13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 7]
```

I then convert the above data (a pandas `DataFrame`) into a `dask.dataframe`

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
```

Now I print the partitions of the `ddf`

```
for p in range(ddf.npartitions):
    print(f"Partition Index={p}, Number of Rows={len(ddf.get_partition(p))}")
>>>
Partition Index=0, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=1, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=2, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=3, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=4, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=5, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=6, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=7, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=8, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=9, Number of Rows=6
```

This is expected. Each partition has 6 rows and one (unique) `store_id`. So, each partition contains data for a single `store_id`.

I now filter the Dask dataframe using the list of `store_id`s from above

```
ddf = ddf[ddf["store_id"].isin(filtered_store_ids)]
```

Again I print the partitions of the filtered `ddf`

```
for p in range(ddf.npartitions):
    print(f"Partition Index={p}, Number of Rows={len(ddf.get_partition(p))}")
>>>
Partition Index=0, Number of Rows=0
Partition Index=1, Number of Rows=0
Partition Index=2, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=3, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=4, Number of Rows=0
Partition Index=5, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=6, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=7, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=8, Number of Rows=0
Partition Index=9, Number of Rows=6
```

This is expected since each partition has one `store_id` and, by filtering, some partitions will be filtered out entirely and so they will contain zero rows.

So, now I'll re-partition the filtered `Dataframe` per [Dask DataFrame best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#repartition-to-reduce-overhead)

```
ddf = ddf.repartition(npartitions=len(filtered_store_ids))
print(ddf)
>>>
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              store_id        A
npartitions=6                  
0                int64  float64
6                  ...      ...
...                ...      ...
48                 ...      ...
59                 ...      ...
Dask Name: repartition, 47 tasks
```

I expected this re-partitioning operation to result in only evenly sized non-empty partitions. **But**, now when I re-print the partitions, I get a similar output to the previous one (uneven partition sizes and some empty partitions), as though the re-partitioning did not happen

```
for p in range(ddf.npartitions):
    print(f"Partition Index={p}, Number of Rows={len(ddf.get_partition(p))}")
>>>
Partition Index=0, Number of Rows=0
Partition Index=1, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=2, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=3, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=4, Number of Rows=12
Partition Index=5, Number of Rows=6
```

My next step is to apply a function to each partition after filtering but this won't work since there are some partitions (pandas `DataFrame`s) that the function cannot handle as they are missing rows.

```
def myadd(df):
    assert df.shape[0] > 0
    ...
    return ...

ddf.map_partitions(myadd)
>>> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
.
.
.
AssertionError:
```

The Dask documentation for re-partitioning is [well-explained](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.repartition) (same for the best practice that I linked above) and it seems simple enough but, after re-partitioning, I am still getting some partitions with zero rows and `map_partitions` will fail here. I'm sure I missing something here.

There are a couple of SO posts about re-partitioning ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642966/repartition-dask-dataframe-to-get-even-partitions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657631/strategy-for-partitioning-dask-dataframes-efficiently)) but they don't deal with empty partitions.

**Question**

Is there a way to ensure that, after re-partitioning, all partitions will have 6 rows again and no empty partitions? i.e. is it possible to have a re-partitioned Dask `DataFrame` with equally sized (non-empty) partitions?

**EDIT**

It looks like empty partitions cannot be dealt with in Dask, at the moment: issues [1](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6167#issuecomment-624277971), [2](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5729). These could be connected to the problem I am experiencing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two existing posts from SO

- remove empty partitions using [`cull_empty_partitions()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613803/4057186)
- rebalance to get even partition sizes using [`_rebalance_ddf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56014192/4057186)

  - **warning** - this function requires computation

and I used them as follows to solve this problem.

Start with the original code from the questions (no changes needed)

```
.
<identical code from question here>
.
ddf = ddf.repartition(npartitions=len(filtered_store_ids))
```

Next, I just call the two functions in succession on the the repartitioned `ddf`

```
ddf = cull_empty_partitions(ddf)  # remove empties
ddf = _rebalance_ddf(ddf)         # re-size
```

When I now re-print partition sizes, all are evenly sized and none are empty

```
for p in range(ddf.npartitions):
    print(f"Partition Index={p}, Number of Rows={len(ddf.get_partition(p))}")
>>>
Partition Index=0, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=1, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=2, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=3, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=4, Number of Rows=6
Partition Index=5, Number of Rows=6
```