# Dask Distributed on local machine metadata column order mismatch with smaller partition sizes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, metadata, dask

When I try to use dask to clean a number of jsonl files it gives me errors saying that the column order is mismatched if I use a partition size of something like 128MB, but works fine if a little slow when I use a size of 512MB

so my code looks something like:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers = 1, threads_per_worker = 4)
meta = dd.utils.make_meta([('x1', 'object'), ('date', 'int64'), ('x2', 'object'])
df = dd.read_json('*.jsonl', blocksize = 2**27, meta = meta)
keep = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
df['x1'] = df.x1.str.lower()
df = df[df['x1'].isin(keep)]
df.to_csv('dask_file.csv', single_file) = True
```

When I run this code I eventually get an error saying that the order of the columns do not match

however, when I run:

```
df = dd.read_json('*.jsonl', blocksize = 2**29, meta = meta)
keep = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
df['x1'] = df[df['x1'].isin(keep)]
df.to_csv(dask_file.csv', single_file = True)
```

It writes what I need, although the speed is quite a bit slower when I look at the progress. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that with the smaller `blocksize` you end up with partitions that are empty after applying the `.isin(keep)` filter. If that is the case, you can remove the empty partitions using the function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613803/10693596).

However, in this situation I would prefer `dask.bag` API, as it's well suited for working with json, see this [example](https://examples.dask.org/applications/json-data-on-the-web.html). If you want csv output at the end, you can convert the bag to dataframe with `.to_dataframe()`.

Comment: By empty do you mean 0 rows? because 0 rows did not throw off the code when I asked it to print the number of rows in each partition. It just suddenly died around the 170th partition.

Comment: Yes, I mean zero rows. The number of partitions in each row probably doesn't involve checking of the column consistency, while `.to_csv` with `single_file` option does. My guess is you would not see the error if you set `single_file=False` (but not sure).

Comment: Alternatively you can check the function in the first link of the updated answer, it will remove empty partitions and your `.to_csv` should work with `single_file=True`.